# Need help figuring out return type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

Here is the method:

```
public IEnumerable<???> GetAllSiteVisits()
{
    var visits =
        _db.STEWARDSHIP
           .OrderByDescending(r => r.VISIT_DATE)
           .Select(r => new
               {
                   id = r.STEWARDSHIP_ID,
                   name = r.SITE.SITE_NAME,
                   visit_date = r.VISIT_DATE,
                   visit_type = r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC
               });
    return visits;
}
```

I am using the `Entity Framework 4.2`.

So the problem is figuring out the return type. If I were just to use the info directly from the DB table, I'd return `IEnumerable<STEWARDSHIP>` but since I am selecting only certain fields, I don't understand what the return type is.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Just `IEnumerable` which defaults to Object as an element type

Comment: @Oybek, that option still leaves the result largely unusable in its present state, as the properties would be invisible and you would have to resort to reflection, dynamic, or some CastByExample trickery.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram  This is quite usable if you use DataBinding via web forms or WPF/Silverlight. If you want to make some manipulations in c# code the named type is a necessity here IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return type will be a collection of `AnonymousType` where each item represents a class with the following properties:

- `id` (with type of the r.STEWARDSHIP_ID)
- `name` (with type of the r.SITE.SITE_NAME)
- `visit_date` (with type of the r.VISIT_DATE)
- `visit_type` (with type of the r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC)

Then you can loop through the elements using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var item in visits)
{
   string visitInfo = String.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Date: {2}, Type: {3}",
                        item.id,
                        item.name,
                        item.visit_date,
                        item = visit_type);

   Debug.WriteLine(visitInfo);       
}
```

If you need to return results of the query from the method you can introduce a new class which represent these fore properties:

```
// TODO: update types of the properties
class VisitDetails
{
   public string Id { get; private set; }
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public DateTime VisitDate { get; private set; }
   public string VisitType { get; private set; }
}
```

And update query to create instances of VisitDetails rather than Anonymous Type:

```
.Select(r => new VisitDetails
    {                      
        Id = r.STEWARDSHIP_ID,                      
        Name = r.SITE.SITE_NAME,
        VisitDate = r.VISIT_DATE,
        VisitType = r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC                  
    });
```

In this way return type would be `IEnumerable<VisitDetails>` so you easily can even return results of the query itself from the method by specifying exact return type as well so code would be much clean.

See [Object Initializers with anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I think this won't work. You can't return IEnumerable<AnonymousType>. Am I wrong?

Comment: `AnonymousType` is a placeholder not a type name, or what you mean? LINQ query would return IEnumerable where each item is of Anonymous type. or you know NON-generic version of `Enumerable.Select()` method?

Comment: One thing here is this only addresses part of the question. You've correctly identified the issue is with building the anonymous type, but you have not addressed how we can return the sequence and be able to use it intuitively.

Comment: You both right guys, I've updated answer to be more correct in terms of return type and also added an example of how-to use sequence returned by an query as well

Comment: @sll: Your answer is more clear now. OP was asking what to put in `???` and your answer was suggesting that he could have `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` and just magically work.

Comment: I've just updated an answer with an example of how-to use further, hope it eliminate downvotes

Comment: Yes, with the concrete type in place, this answer is much better.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram, Icarus: thanks for helping me improve answer quality

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to, it's returning an Anonymous type. Read [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) on this topic.

One alternative would be to create a concrete implementation using a class that has

- id
- name
- visit_date
- visit_type

as properties

Comment: This is more than an *alternative*, it's the right thing to do. Anonymous types are useful when they are self-contained within a given method. Once you start passing them around, it's time to go ahead and promote it to a properly-defined class.

Comment: While what you suggest is the right thing to do, note that you *can* return an `IEnummerable` of an anonymous type, if it's typed as plain (non-generic) `IEnumerable`. But then (as @Anthony points out elsewhere) consumers have to be messy to get into the objects.

Comment: @AakashM: Correct. You either return `IEnumerable<object>` and then use reflection or use some sort of trick to return a concrete type (CastByExample was mentioned above), none of which look like a good approach to me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return an AnonymousType as a return value from a method. You will have to create a type which you populate in your linq:

```
    public IEnumerable<SiteVisit> GetAllSiteVisits()
{
    var visits =
        _db.STEWARDSHIP
           .OrderByDescending(r => r.VISIT_DATE)
           .Select(r => new SiteVisit
               {
                   Id = r.STEWARDSHIP_ID,
                   Name = r.SITE.SITE_NAME,
                   VisitDate = r.VISIT_DATE,
                   VisitType = r.VISIT_TYPE_VAL.VISIT_TYPE_DESC
               });
    return visits;
}
```