# how to get the index of the widget and why is it giving only first value

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am using the code below

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<widgets>
    <widget>
        <url>~/Portal/Widgets/ServicesList.ascx</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>ascx</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>3</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
    <widget>
        <url>www.omegacoder.com</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>htm</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>41</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>";

XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse( xml );

var widgets = from x in loaded.Descendants( "widget" )
              select new
              {
                  URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value,
                  Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value
              };

foreach ( var wd in widgets )
    Console.WriteLine( "Widget at ({0}) has a category of {1}", wd.URL, wd.Category );
```

This gives me the URL and Category for the first widget only? Not sure how can I get the values for second one. 
Also how can I get the index of the widget like 0 and 1 and so on....depending on how many widgets are there.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query return entries for both widgets for me, I've tried your code without any changes.

Following query will help you get index for each widget as well:

```
var widgets = loaded.Descendants("widget").Select((w, i) =>
                   new
                   {        
                     WidgetIndex = i,
                     URL = w.Descendants( "url" )
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            .Value,
                     Category = w.Descendants("PortalCategoryId")
                                 .FirstOrDefault()
                                 .Value
                   });
```

String representation:

```
string widgetsInfo = 
    loaded.Descendants("widget")
          .Select((w, i) =>
                new
                    {
                        WidgetIndex = i,
                        URL = w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        Category = w.Descendants("PortalCategoryId").FirstOrDefault().Value
                    })
            .Select(w => String.Format("Index:{0}; URL:{1}; CATEGORY:{2}; ",
                                        w.WidgetIndex, w.URL, w.Category))
            .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + Environment.NewLine + next);
```

Comment: I think you are adding it to a list. how would I do a messagebox for the values and indexes just so I know they are correct in the app

Comment: You would have a list of items of anonymous type, do you have some kind of widget class? Otherwise just put all in string so this would ens up as `List<string>`

Comment: I dont have a widget class. I am new to C# and dont know much arguments. How would I convert it to an array. Cause I will need to send it to a different method in an array

Comment: See my updated answer, I've added query which dump string info for you, also see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8139568/485076) to see how to return concrete type instances from anonymous type instances, but if you would have concrete class which represents a widget you can select from XML and create widget class instances without intermediate anonymous types

Comment: one more quick question. what if the value of  URL = w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault().Value, or the node url or etc is missing. then it will throw an error. How can I prevent that. thanks

Comment: CHeck for null `w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault()` before accessing Value property, `w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault() == null ? String.Empty : w.Descendants("url").FirstOrDefault().Value`